# Include h-file with definitions inside in multiple cpp-files

Tags: c++, linker-errors

My problem is that I have header-file (custom unit-test framework) with function definitions in it. For example:
**unit_test.h:**

```
#pragma once
...    
void Assert(bool b, const string& hint = {})
{
    AssertEqual(b, true, hint);
}
...
```

it's convenient for me to keep some functions defined right in the header, because I often use this functional by simply including (`unit_test.h` is located in separate directory `C:/Dev/include`). 
But if I am dealing with a project where multiple cpp files use this functionality, I get a multiple definition error as expected.
Simple project looks like:
**main.cpp:**

```
#include "unit_test.h"

void foo();

int main()
{
    Assert(1);
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.cpp:**

```
#include "unit_test.h"

void foo()
{
    Assert(2);
}
```

So I want to know if there is a right way to keep function definitions in a header file and use it in project without getting an multiple definition error?
 (*Or would it be better to move the function definitions to the source and compile it separately each time, or compile unit_test into a static library?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve it, is to add `inline` keyword in function definiton, but it's not a best solution.

Best option is to move definition to source file, but only it it's not a template.

Answer (score 1):

I would use anonymous namespace with inline:

```
namespace {
    inline void Assert(bool b, const string& hint = {})
    {
        AssertEqual(b, true, hint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is beacuse whenever you will include the file it will define the function again. The solution is make a header file **unit_test.h** with declaration only and create a source file **unit_test.cpp** for definition. Now you can include header file it will not give error. Don't forget to add #ifndef in header as follow

**unit_test.h**

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST_H_
#define UNIT_TEST_H_
// Declare you function
// and end with:
#endif
```

Comment: There is already `#pragma once`.